# Trackpad and keyboard not working on MacBook Air Retina 2018

Tags: keyboard, touchpad, macbook, usb

Trying to run a live version USB drive for testing - elementary OS 5.0 Juno

The same USB runs the build just fine on my 2015 iMac but I get no trackpad and keyboard function on my MacBook Air Retina 2018.

Is there a build with all up to date drivers included? Am I missing something?

Thank you in advance for any help.